# How to know what user modified a file in windows environment using powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, automation

I would like for your suggestion to see if there a way to tell who accessed/modified/delete a specific file on windows using Powershell command or batch command without the need to turn on file level logging on a windows host? The following Powershell command doesn't necessarily give me the username of who modified the file.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Test Folder' | Where {$_.LastWriteTime} | select -last 1
```

Comment: You would need to enable auditing on the files you needed to monitor and then read from the logs generated.

Answer (score 2):

Windows file auditing is not on by default. If the file is not currently reporting audit information, you will not be able to get this information. if you choose to turn it on, future auditing event information is logged into a Windows log. It is not stored in the file metadata.  (caution: turning on file auditing can result in an inadvertent denial of service due to the large amounts of data potentially generated.) 
Auditing can be enabled by open file Explorer and navigating to the folder/file  you wish to audit.

- Right click on the file
- Select Security Tab
- Click Advanced button
- Click Auditing Tab (elevate privledges)
- Click Add
- Select a Principle (can be Users or Domain Users), Select which permissions you wish to audit (maybe Write)
- Click OK

Once this is done, audit entries should show up in the Windows Security log.

Comment: so, how to enable it, and where is the log?